# Smoothing of 2D curve with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, curve, smoothing

I am trying to plot closed curves in Python from 2D data. For doing this I am using the ConvexHull function, i.e. doing

```
hull = ConvexHull(array_of_points)
xhull = array_of_points[hull.vertices,0]
yhull = array_of_points[hull.vertices,1]
plt.plot(xhull, yhull)
```

I obtain plots like this:
[image]

Now, how can I do to "transform" these in nice, smooth elliptical-like curves? I already tried with spline interpolation (i.e. with functions splprep, splev), but I obtain results which are definitely not so nice...
[image]

What would you suggest me for smoothing in the nicest possible way a curve like this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Spline interpolation is indeed an option. You probably just made a mistake somewhere (or possibly did not take the log scale into account?). But one cannot know with the information at hand.

Comment: You probably also need to append the first point again at the end to obtain a closed polygon

Comment: Are there constraints (i.e. does the smooth curve have to actually still accurately mathematically represent something) or is this purely for visual purposes? If the latter, forming a Catmull-Rom curve through the points should be more than enough.